# SQLite open database from string

Tags: java, sqlite

Assume I have a string containing an sqlite database.
(I read the entire content of the file containing the Sqlite database into a string)

Now, I want to get a connection to the database  **without saving the string to a file first**.

Basically, this is an in-memory data base, which is totally possible in sqlite. But according to the sqlite [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html)  "[when you open an in memory data base] no disk file is opened. Instead, a new database is created purely in memory".

But I have string representing a data base. i want to use it and not create a new one.

Can this be done?

Comment: You have a database in xml? Please explan or give examples. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Its not a database in xml. I have an xml file that contains a lot of nodes, and each node hold a different kind of data. There is one node that contains the entire text of an sqlite3 file. if i take this text and save it to a file, i can (successfully) connect to it using the sqlite driver. But I want to do it without saving the text to a file.

Answer (score 0):

In-memory databases do not give you access to the underlying memory.

It is possible to copy databases with the [backup API](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html), but that would require another, file-based database.

Just create a temporary file, and open it directly.

Comment: It actually specifically says: "It cannot be used to copy data to or from in-memory databases."  So i guess its not possible to do what i wanted. But thanks for the answer!!